Dependent tables replications using Kafka
We need to replicate near 120 Firebird (FB) tables to Postgres with foreign key constraints. FB doesn't support CDC.
As I understand only JDBC driver can be used for this purpose. We can use increment or timestamp column to query tables into Kafka using Kafka connect.
Updates can be properly tracked using timestamp with modification time column. At this moment we don't consider deletion only upsert operations. According to this some message lost can occur for timestamp approach that is not acceptable for us.
Is there any better solution for this problem? The requirement is to use Kafka.
